# use bigrock email in godaddy hosting

Tags: email, opencart, mailing

i have a open cart website on my go-daddy hosting, my C-panel email in go-daddy is having some issue and the go-daddy is working on it. till then i want to use the email of my BIG ROCK hosting.
i want to know the SMTP settings of Big Rock and the MX entry

Answer (score 0):

When ever you login in to the CPANEL , you will get this notice on the top.

Attention! Please register your email IDs used in non-smtp mails through cpanel plugin. Unregistered email IDs will not be allowed in non-smtp emails sent through scripts. 
Go to Mail section and find "Registered Mail IDs" plugin in paper_lantern theme.

Just follow these steps and it will work.